# Passing an attribute in JQuery form fadeIn

Tags: jquery

Can we pass HTML attribute ID while opening a FORM on click ?
I have below code

```
$(".abc").on("click",function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $(".XYZ-form").fadeIn("fast");
}
```

I want to pass var id to XYZ-form so that once form is displayed that attribute will be shown.

HTML form is in below format

```
<div class=".XYZ-form">
  <table>
    <tr>
     <TD>attribute value</TD>
     <TD input type="text" value=""></TD>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here value should display value of var id from jquery.

Comment: Are you sure  you mean `<TD input type="text" value=""></TD>` and not `<TD><input type="text" value=""><input></TD>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use second parameter of `fadeIn` method - function, which is executed when animation completes. In that function you can do whatever you need to do (as it is not very clear what you mean by `pass var id to XYZ-form`):

```
$(".abc").on("click",function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $(".XYZ-form").fadeIn("fast", function(){
     // this function is executed when animation completes

     // access the form that was animated
     var formThatWasAnimated = $(this);
     // find first input element on the form
     var firstInputElementInTheForm = formThatWasAnimated.find('input:first');
     // set the value of input element
     firstInputElementInTheForm.val(id);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i want to use var id on form XYZ. Means when form opens value of variable id should be displayed on the form.

Comment: @SwapnilRanadive So what type of element is `XYZ-form`? Is it text input or something else?

Comment: This is form with few attributes where user will add some values..but for that he needs to see value of var id on the form.

Comment: @SwapnilRanadive Form is just a grouping element, it does not have visual representation. You cannot display anything on form, you can only display data on element inside the form (e.g. `input` element). Please update the question with you HTML and also clearly explain what you want to achieve

Comment: @SwapnilRanadive I see that, however your HTML is invalid you need to have `input` element inside `td`, not as attributes of `td`.

Comment: Really appreciate, this helped. Thank you !!

Comment: One more question, here we have used .find('input:first'). Can we find element with its id in this format ?